# React child route don't work when directly pasted in browser url but does work when navigate through home page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, azure-appservice

I have react application that is deployed on Azure App Service.

I cannot find resource if I paste any other url than home page in react app but works fine when I browse any page.

For example `"https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/about"` wont work if I paste url directly into browser but will work if I navigate from home page. This is only happening on the deployed website on azure app service and no issue on localhost.

I have not configured any routes in azure App service. Do I need any thing there?

App Route

```
import React from "react";
import ...

export const routes = [
  { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
  { path: "/home", element: <Home /> },
  { path: "/authlogin", element: <AuthLogin /> },
  { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
  { path: "/contactus", element: <ContactUs /> },
  { path: "*", element: <Error404 /> },
 ];
```

Index.js

```
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { ParallaxProvider } from "react-scroll-parallax";

const instance = new PublicClientApplication(MsalConfiguration);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render( 
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MsalProvider instance={instance}>
        <ParallaxProvider>
          <App />
        </ParallaxProvider>
      </MsalProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { routes } from "./configurations/App/AppRoutes";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  
 return (
   <div>
    <Routes>
      {routes.map((route, index) => (
        <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
      ))}
    </Routes>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

json routes

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Home",
    "link": "/"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "About",
    "link": "/about",
    "subMenu": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Services",
    "link": "/services",
    "subMenu": [
      {
        "title": "Airport",
        "link": "/services/airport"
      },
      {
        "title": "Executive Chauffeur",
        "link": "/services/executive-chauffeur"
      },
      {
        "title": "Wedding",
        "link": "/services/wedding"
      },
      {
        "title": "Wheelchair",
        "link": "/services/wheelchair"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Booking",
    "link": "/booking",
    "subMenu": false
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Contact",
    "link": "/contactus"
  }
]
```

Comment: See if reading through the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#azure) for Azure will help. The basic gist is that the server/hosting service needs to be configured to return the root index.html file for ***all*** page requests into the app so the app is mounted and can handle routing/navigation internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App Service uses IIS routing rules for the application. You can resolve this problem by adding Routing configuration file in your Project's public folder.

Web.config File

```
    <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/(api)" negate="true" />
              
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Take a build of the application. And host it again